# How can I use google maps inside Vue.js in ES6

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, vue.js

I want to use google maps and jquery, inside Vue.js in ES6.

I dont want it to be a component or anything like vue-google-maps.
I just want to import google maps, and use like I always use it.

Ive got jquery working like so.

```
  import jQuery from 'jquery'
  var jq = window.Jquery = jQuery
```

Now I want to do the same for google maps, so that I can have access to the 'google' variable. and use it in the mounted() method. like so...

```
  export default {
      mounted () {
           var map = google.maps///etc
      }
  }
```

I can't seem to import it anyway I try.  ANd if I just include the script on the  index.html page its not available even if I make it a global object.  Because its created after Vue.js

I already tried vue-google-maps, but my use case is highly specific, and I need alot of old code Ive already written, so I just need the plain old google maps NOT AS A VUE COMPONENT.

I guess you could say, I want this part of my App, to not be under Vue control at all.  Just plain old Jquery, after mounting.

Please help!

Comment: why the downvote?  explain yourself downvoter lol

Answer (score 1):

yes, you are right.It's actually not a Vue problem. It's an JavaScript module problem.

As google map is written in IIFE mode, you can't just import it. You better translate it into UMD or commonjs mode.

If you are not sure how to do.Maybe you can take this for a look. [google-maps](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js)

you can write such a module, for Example, my-google-map.js

```
import 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js'
export default window.google
```

then in your vue file

```
import google from 'my-google-map.js'
console.log(google)
```

Comment: I tried google-maps module.  I just get an error that says.  this.setValues is not a function, when trying to initiate a map though.   It loads fine, as I can console log it just fine.  But when I initiate a map, I get an error.  So maybe its old, or not being maintained anymore.  You would think this would be a very easy to find module that many have replicated.  But I guess not?

Comment: yep, i agree that.So i suggest you not to just use that module.. But as i have not use google maps at all. I can't give some very good solution. However, i think it's more like a umd, iife etc problem.Maybe you can just wrap by yourself. oh, i have a good idea. i edit the anwser.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the following?

```
<div>
 <img class="google-map" :src="googleUrl()">
</div>

methods: {
      googleUrl () {
        return 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=16&scale=2&markers=color:blue|' + this.fullAddress() + '&size=250x200&sensor=false'
      },
      fullAddress () {
        return this.streetname + ' ' + this.housenumber + ',' + this.zipcode + ' ' + this.city
}
```

Comment: Because I need the maps full interactivity.  Streetview, Infowindows, scrolling, zooming.  Essentially my whole app, is focused on a map.